# MoveBaseGoal: ROS2 equivalent

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there is a ROS2 equivalent of the `move_base_msgs.msg : MoveBaseGoal` from ROS1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398697/movebasegoal:-ros2-equivalent/) by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2022-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like the ROS2 version is `geometry_msgs.msg : PoseStamped`

---

Originally posted by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) with karma: 170 on 2022-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2022-04-08**:
Thank you so much for your time to post the solution!